# What is the private page?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, kernel

In the page struct, there is private field.
If I use page_buffers() function, they return that field.

And also there is PrivatePage(). 
But I dont know what it is.

What is this?

Answer (score 9):

See include/linux/page-flags.h:

```
 * Private page markings that may be used by the filesystem that owns the page
 * for its own purposes.
 * - PG_private and PG_private_2 cause releasepage() and co to be invoked
```

And also Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt:

> An address_space handler may attach extra information to a page,
>   typically using the 'private' field in the 'struct page'.  If such
>   information is attached, the PG_Private flag should be set.  This will
>   cause various VM routines to make extra calls into the address_space
>   handler to deal with that data.

`page_buffers()` is for the specific case where the `private` field contains a pointer to a `struct buffer_head`, which is a very common pattern in filesystem drivers.